# Move comment discard instruction text in iOS App

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, design, ios-app

Can you please move the text that reads "*Swipe left to discard comment*" out of the text entry field in the iOS App?

[image: Current text placement]

I'll be honest, I'm not a huge fan of the swipe to discard in the first place but, particularly in the landscape view of the iPad version of the app, getting out of a comment field can be frustrating if you're not aware of the "swipe left to discard" option... which I usually forget about and I usually don't notice the text when I start my comment... and by the time I need to trash a half-written comment, the helper text is gone. At least in the iPhone version, you can click the back arrow to get out of the question and discard the comment. There's no way to do that in the landscape view of the iPad app.

[image: iPhone View]

When text is inserted, the note disappears:

[image: No help text.]

#### My suggestion:

Move the discard text to the space below the comment field. There's already some text there, so mirror it on the other side. This means that users always know how to discard their comment.

Updated iPad view:
[image: New Placement for text iPad]

Updated iPhone view:
[image: New Placement for text iPhone]

There seems to be plenty of space for the text, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be added in 1.4.3.7, shipping towards the end of January.

The main concern I had about this was with narrow form factors (both iPhone 4S and Slide Over on an iPad) but that can just be trimmed to "Swipe left to discard" without coming anywhere near the character count text.

[image: Screenshot showing the swipe message below the comment.]